# DataSet's Table name from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, ado.net

I am using a stored procedure to fill a DataSet.  What I need to do is force the name of the DataTable that is created when filled.  There are multiple tables returned from the Stored Procedure.  The last table is the one I need to make sure has a specific name when returned.  It is created by returning a value of a variable and not pulling from any tables.

SELECT @Phone as My_800Number

How can I make this return as table called "D1Header"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ADO.NET Native way to do it; ADO.Net assign a generated name with a sequence number, according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(VS.80).aspx)

You can workaround it... if you say you need the last table with a specific name, you can do:

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
  ds.Tables[ds.Tables.Count - 1].TableName = "name";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could use an enum of the table names and reference that in your table reference rather than the table itself.

ds.tables(myEnum.Contacts).rows ?