# getting sql table name aliases from SP to ASP.NET C# code

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a SP with 20 select queries. Each query is table-name-aliased like below.

```
Create procedure sp_get_all_lists
 as
 begin
   select col1, col2 from tb_ nm as name
   select col1, col2 from tb_ctry as country
   select col1, col2 from tc_cty city
    .
    .
    .
   select col1, col2 from tb_prfl as profile
  end
```

I need to bind all the data to dropdown lists in ASP.NET C# web page. While binding, if the query is executed, the DataTable array in DataSet, have the names as Table1, Table2... etc. I need the datatables to bear the alias names i gave in the SP.

This would help me bind the dropdowns as

```
ddCtry.DataSource = ds.Tables["country"];
```

Currently am doing it as `ddCtry.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];`

Could someone help me to get the table-alias name in C# code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there seems to be no ADO.NET native way to do this. did you try looking at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804443/datasets-table-name-from-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this (as of .NET 4.0) See the "Multiple Result sets" sections of:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx

and also this question:
[set the result table name in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602810/set-the-result-table-name-in-stored-procedure)

You could try using Linq